# How to get a list of projects from a position in LinkedIn-J

Tags: java, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

How could I get a list of projects from a position in LinkedIn-J? If it is not straightforwardly possible, how could I get a list of projects from a person/user/profile?

The [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/w/list) said nothing as far as I've seen and so I tried to use the autocomplete from Eclipse to see all methods from Persons, clients etc. etc.

Comment: I took the liberty of moving your comment into your question.  Sorry to not be able to help.  Best of luck.

Comment: Here's the Javadocs which I assume you have already: http://linkedin-j.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/linkedin-j/doc/index.html  Here's the docs for Person: http://linkedin-j.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/linkedin-j/doc/com/google/code/linkedinapi/schema/Person.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, [LinkedIn API does not provide a way to retrieve projects](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/how-can-one-gets-list-projects-user) currently, so LinkedIn-J cannot do it.